# Can't do a full backup because the log is full

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I have a server with 25GB of free space. The software stopped working because the transaction log is full. I noticed that the database has two logs files; one is 45Gb and the other is 65Gb.

I think the guy working here before me (he is not anymore) added a second log file so the software would continue working, however there is almost no space left on disk.

I tried using SQL Server Management Studio to take a full backup but I can't since the transaction log is full.

What are my options? I can shrink the logs but I don't have **ANY** backup and can't do any of them.

Should I change it to simple mode first? Can I script the whole database and save it as 'backup'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't have space in your drives to take a log backup. You can use the following query to trick SQL server into thinking that you are actually saving the log backup to disk, But you're not.

```
BACKUP LOG dbname TO DISK = 'NUL:';
```

Also if you're running SQL server 2005 or less, You can use the below query

```
BACKUP LOG dbname WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY;
```

Once the query completes you can go ahead and shrink the log file as usual using

```
USE dbname;
DBCC SHRINKFILE(fileid , 0);
```

Also do note that the above backup query will break your log backup chain and your log-shipping setup, if you have one.

Comment: good advice, however you should always ensure you take a full backup and ensure regular database and log backups are scheduled after doing a backup to `disk='NUL:'`